# Create a custom GSON Deserialization to map JSON response to object in Android

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm using GSON library to map JSON response from API and map to an object.

Here is my URL link:

```
https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json?print=pretty
```

And my model class `TopStory`

```
public class TopStory implements Comparable<TopStory> {
    int id;
    String title;
    String by;
    int score;
    List<Integer> kids;
    long time;
    String url;



    public TopStory() {
    }

    public TopStory(int id, String title, String by, int score, long time,String url,List kids) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.by = by;
        this.score = score;
        this.time = time;
        this.url = url;
        this.kids = kids;
    }
```

and i'm create a function to create an object from JSON response:

```
public static TopStory fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        TopStory topStory = new TopStory();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        topStory = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(),TopStory.class);
```

I'm having problem with the field kids. from Response it's an `JSONARRAY`. how can we deserialize and map to and object field `List`. And how me exclude to manually Deserialize and assign to specific field?

Comment: create models through: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Hi does it support deserializtion from json?

Comment: yes, use it for creating models, rest of your work will be same.

Comment: Do you have an example how to use that. I tried but have problem integrate with gradle

Comment: post your code and error..

Answer (score 1):

Actually `kids` is not a `List`, it's an `Array`, so declare `kids` like this

```
Integer[] kids;
```

Comment: Thanks for yrs response. Should we use int[] kids or Integer[] kids?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Retrofit to make api calls et create a serializable model to get datas.

Comment: Actually i'm using volley as it support caching resquest and request priority

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
TopStory topStory = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(),TopStory.class);
```

`List<Integer> kids;`// **Correct declaration**